# Condensing wide dataframe with columnwise operations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rbind, mutate

I'm still learning R and was wondering if I there was an elegant way of manipulating the below df to achieve df2.

I'm not sure if it's a loop that is supposed to be used for this, but basically for each V(X)_Type(X) column (excl. Proxy columns), I would like to subtract each row value from the first row stopping when Proxy_Type(X) hits 99999.

This probably sounds confusing in words so hopefully an example from df to the desired df2 will assist in visualising what I'm trying to ask.

```
Type1 <- c('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO','PQR')
V1_Type1 <- c('1','0.5','1','0.2','3','4')
V2_Type1 <- c('2','0.5','1','0.3','3.2','4.1')
V3_Type1 <- c('3','0.6','1','0.4','3.3','4.3')
Proxy_Type1 <- c('0','99999','99999','99999','99999','99999')

Type2 <- c('DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO','PQR','STU')
V1_Type2 <- c('0.5','1','0.2','3','4','4.2')
V2_Type2 <- c('0.5','1','0.3','3.2','4.1','2.2')
V3_Type2 <- c('0.6','1','0.4','3.3','4.3','3')
Proxy_Type2 <- c('0','1.35','99999','99999','99999','99999')

Type3 <- c('GHI','JKL','MNO','PQR','STU','VWX')
V1_Type3 <- c('1','0.2','3','4','4.2','4.1')
V2_Type3 <- c('1','0.3','3.2','4.1','2.2','1.8')
V3_Type3 <- c('1','0.4','3.3','4.3','3','4.2')
Proxy_Type3 <- c('0','2.5','3','99999','99999','99999')



df <- data.frame(Type1,V1_Type1,V2_Type1,V3_Type1,Proxy_Type1,
                 Type2,V1_Type2,V2_Type2,V3_Type2,Proxy_Type2,
                 Type3,V1_Type3,V2_Type3,V3_Type3,Proxy_Type3)


To <- c('DEF','GHI','GHI')
From <- c('GHI','JKL','MNO')
V1 <- c('0.5','-0.8','2')
V2 <- c('0.5','-0.7','2.2')
V3 <- c('0.4','-0.6','2.3')

df2 <- data.frame(To,From,V1,V2,V3)
```

So in the desired df2 dataframe, you can see that there is no To and From "ABC" "DEF", since "DEF" Proxy is 99999 and it instantly skips to "DEF" to "GHI" then V1= (1-0.5), V2=(1-0.5), V3=(1-0.6) stopping at GHI since JKL has Proxy_Type2 = 99999. Moving onto Type3, "GHI" to "JKL" V1=(0.2-1), V2=(0.3-1), V3=(0.4-1) then "GHI" to "MNO" V1=(3-1), V2=(3.2-1), V3=(3.3-1). The process will stop here since PQR has 99999.

I have hundreds of these "Type" types of columns where I would like to produce such a calculation from df to df2 much too time consuming manually and would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thankyou

Comment: I would need some more explanation of how you go from `df` to `df2` and also what the single columns / variables mean.

Comment: Thanks @TimTeaFan for reaching out. Df2 is a condensed version of Df where for each type(x) we subtract each row value from the initial 1st row until we hit a row with 99999 in the proxy column at which we stop and then move onto the next type(x) column. The numeric variables themselves are really of no contextual importance just some values I dummied up, it is the process of how this is to be done that I am most interested in. Thank you

Comment: Why in Type 3 there is no `JKL to MNO`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time to understand the question. The solution is simple if you first [tidy](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) the data. In this case, that means first pivoting your `df` longer so that `Type` is a variable and not part of each variable name.

Assuming the data is ordered by row number (`idx` in the example below), you simply do the following within each `Type` (using `group_by()`): keep rows before first Proxy == 99999; do your calculation (current row minus first row); set `To` and `From` based on current and first row; and remove the first row. Then keeping the columns `To`, `From`, `V1`...Vx, gives you `df2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-idx) %>%
  mutate(
    Type = gsub(".*Type(\\d).*", "\\1", name),
    name = name %>%
      gsub("_Type\\d", "", .) %>%
      gsub("^Type\\d+$", "tofrom", .)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  arrange(Type, idx) %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  filter(row_number() < which(Proxy == 99999)[1]) %>%
  mutate(
    across(matches("V"), \(x) as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(x)[1]),
    To = tofrom[1],
    From = tofrom
  ) %>%
  filter(row_number() != 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(To, From, matches("V"))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  To    From     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 DEF   GHI     0.5   0.5   0.4
2 GHI   JKL    -0.8  -0.7  -0.6
3 GHI   MNO     2     2.2   2.3
```